# Need help with setting up Li-ion battery parameters in a Solar Charge Controller?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, lithium-ion

I am trying to set up the parameters for a LiFePO4 battery bank for a solar charge controller. I have tried to search the internet for understanding the parameters listed in the charge controller, but couldn't find any direct specification from where I would be able to calculate the parameters. So please pardon my ignorance regarding the basics.

The charge controller I am using is: Wanderer by RENOGY.
The battery bank is consisted of 7 individual Li-ion battery cells (2500 mAh, 3.7 V) in parallel and three such paralleled cells in series.

The aim is to disconnect the load from the battery when the battery voltage would become <10 V. Also, the voltage level of individual cells shouldn't be more than 4.15 V and less than 3 V. Depending on these conditions, how should I set up the below parameters in the charge controller?

High Volt Disconnect(V)
Charge Limit Voltage(V)
Equalize Charge Volt(V)
Boost Charge Volt(V)
Float Charge Volt(V)
Boost Charge Return Volt(V)
Over Disc Return Volt(V)
Low Voltage Alarm(V)
Over Discharge Volt(V)
Over Disc Relay Time(S)
Equalize Charge Time(Min)
Boost Charge Time(Min)
Equalize Charge Interval
Temperature Compensation(mv/C/2V)

Thanks

Comment: _"The battery bank is consisted of 7 individual LiFePO4 battery cells (2500 mAh, 3.7 V)"_ - LiFePO4 cells are not 3.7V. Please confirm the actual cell voltage and chemistry.

Comment: Bruce is right. These numbers would kill an LiFePO4 battery but are about right for Li-Ion. Do not proceed before understanding exactly whatyou are trying to do.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, I am using 'Murata US186503 VTC5' battery cells for this project. The rated voltage is 3.7V written on the cylindrical battery cells . Practically I'm getting around 3.35~3.45 V out of the cells.
And I was wrong. It's Li-ion battery. The battery chemistry is probably LiMnCoO2. So, please guide me how can I determine the parameters stated in the OP.
Thanks

Comment: I read the manual for the Renogy Wanderer Li 30A. Is that your controller? Seems parameters can only be adjusted using the Bluetooth module. Do you have one? If so, what are the available settings for Li-ion?

Comment: @BruceAbbott , Yes, it is my controller.Yes, parameters can only be adjusted through Bluetooth module and I have one. There is an app through which I can connect to the controller and change the settings.
The available settings for 'Battery' are as follows:
High V Discon : 16
Charge Limit V : 15.5
Equalize Charge V : 14.4
Boost Charge V: 14.4
Float Charge V: 14.4
Boost Charge Return V : 13.2
Over Discharge Return V: 12.6
Low Volt Alarm: 12.1
Over Discharge V: 11.1
Discharge Limit V: 10.6
Over Discharge Delay Time: 5 sec
Equalize Charge Time: 0 Min
Equalize Charge Interval: -

Comment: @BruceAbbott, and the available parameters for Load are as follows:
Load Mode: Testing mode; Light Control Delay Time: 10 Min; Light Control Volt: 5 V; 1st Work Time: 4 Hours; 1st Work Time Power : 100%; 2nd Work Time: 0 hour; 2nd Work Time Power: 75%; 3rd Work Time: 4 Hours; 3rd Work Time Power: 50%; Morning Lighting Time: 0 Hour; Morning Lightning Power: 25%.

I tried to contact Renogy for a bit explanation about these functions but didn't get any response. Looking forward for your valuable guideline. Thanks

Comment: You need to check check the complete cell data sheet to get all information you need. Only the values printed on the cells will not give you everythin you need. Where are the settings for the cell temperatures? You will need them for LiIon cells. Or is there an additional BMS attached which can protect your cells from overcurrent and temperature?

Comment: @A.R.C. , in the solar charger battery settings, the temperature setting is : Temperature Compensation(mv/C/2V) and the bydefault value for this '0'. No there is no additional BMS attached. As the parameters of this solar charger are looking a bit confusing to me, I'm thinking of using an additional BMS(cost effective) circuit which would serve the purposes stated in the original post? Thanks